# Meaning of the phrasal verb "set out" in context

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I have stumbled upon it in this [article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-49986007).

> The nationalists are unconvinced by Mr Zelensky's promises to safeguard Ukraine's interests and not to cross his "red lines", **set out** in an urgent news briefing after the deal was signed:

Comment: ***set out** = **defined, described, explained** [in detail]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression "set out" has a number of definitions, but the relevant definition in this context is:

> If you set out a number of facts, beliefs, or arguments, you explain them in writing or speech in a clear, organized way.
>   *([Collins English dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/set-out))*

Comment: What do you mean you *paraphrased* the Collins definition? What was the *actual* definition? You really need to provide an exact quote—and then give your own interpretation if you think it's wrong in some way. Also, Merriam-Webster most certainly does have definitions for the verb [*set out*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set%20out). The way you've presented your answer simply makes it appear as if you don't like any actual dictionary definitions and are providing your own—but also *vaguely* pointing to references to others to give your personal opinion an appearance of authority.

Comment: @JasonBassford Sorry my answer made you assume I don't like dictionaries. Your reply, in the face of the "be nice to new users" alert, makes me think you are threatened by new users. Anyway, I've updated it to include a full quote.

Comment: That's much better, and the actual link is also good. +1 with those changes; this is the kind of thing we look for. ;)